# Menu contruido não está abrindo com o 'arrastar'

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Estou testando alguns componentes do Ionic 2. Instalei via usb um aplicativo com um menu simples, que possui uns itens. Quando tento abrir o menu lateral 'arrastando', não funciona, apenas clicando no botão de menu. Meu dispositivo é o Zenfone 5 com o android 4.4.2.

```
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="openPage(page)">
        {{ page.title }}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Também realizei o download de um projeto `tutorial` do ionic 2 disponibiliza para quem está começando, mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Cara aquele projeto exemplo básico deles já funciona isso ai. Acho meio difícil você conseguir uma resposta, porque seu código não está completo aqui.

Comment: @AckLay Sim sim. Coloca-lo todo ocuparia muito espaço. Imaginei que poderia algo relacionado a versão do Android ou algo relacionado., mas não achei nada que comprovasse isso. Pq o código deles certamente funciona.

Comment: Eu tenho um projeto aqui que ele está basicamente desta form que você colocou ai, porém no ion-nav está assim : `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>`

Comment: @AckLay não funcionou nem com false nem com true :/

Comment: @AckLay instalei um cara chamado `crosswalk`. Parece que o webview do meu celular não suporta direito ionic2 e Angular2, então algumas funcionalidades não funcionam mesmo. Crosswalk resolve isso, em contra partida tem umas 3x mais tamanho que um app normal teria.

Comment: Que zika isso! Nunca vi nenhuma situação em que o webview de algum modele não funcionasse. Você testou sua aplicação no browser e funciona normalmente o drawer?

Comment: Não vejo problema em aumentar um pouco o tamanho do app. O ruim é se isso influenciará a questão da performance da aplicação. Pelo que li do crosswalk melhora tanto desempenho, quanto previsibilidade.

Comment: @AckLay. Sim no browser funciona normalmente, mas também, até agora, apenas isso deu problema em relação ao webview, o restante das coisas estão funcionando... Pois é, eu só estou realizando testes com esse dispositivo, mas dependendo do aplicativo, se for necessário, vale a pena instalar esse CrossWalk.